# How to turn off the boot up beep of Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: boot

I have recently bought a Yoga 2 Pro i5 version and a Seagate Backup Plus Slim 1TB Mobile USB HDD. I made a 4GB partition and used the Universal USB Installer to write the ISO into the partition with few GBs Persistence storage. Whenever I boot up the Ubuntu Live from the HDD in my Yoga 2 Pro, it makes a very loud beep if the following page is arrived. (I don't have the permission to upload images)

---

### Ubuntu

### Installer boot menu

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- Check disc for defects
- Test memory
- Boot from first hard disk
- Advanced options >
- Help

---

This makes me embarrassed since everybody looks at me if I would like to use Ubuntu to do my assignments at quiet places such as library or computer lab. How can I turn off the boot up beep permanently? Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu operates normally except that I hate the beep sound very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boot should only happen when you're not booting in UEFI mode (which would be pretty much always on old systems). It's due to this line in the Syslinux configuration (`isolinux/menu.cfg`):

```
menu title Installer boot menu^G
```

If you're using an USB, it should be enough to edit that file and remove the beep, which is caused by the `^G` (or ASCII bell - `\a` - character).

Source:

- [Debian forums: SOLVED! disable "BEEP" from syslinux by wheezy hdd live](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=76588)

Comment: Working on ubuntu 16.04 and 15.10!

Answer (score -2):

in 02.2018

where it says:
menu title Boot menuBEL

remove the BEL

I had to download SCite to do this, as my text editor